# Regex in PHP between /* & */ for preg-match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to extract all substrings in a string that is between the strings /* and */. I know this will probably need to be done with regular expressions however I'm having a hard time getting the correct regex since the star character is actually used to symbolise repeated characters. I'm am trying to use the preg-match method in PHP here is what I have come up with so far but I'm not having much luck.

```
<?php
   $aString = "abcdef/*ghij*/klmn/*opqrs*/tuvwxyz";
   preg_match("/*/.*/", $aString, $anArray);

   for ($i = 0; $i < count($anArray); i++)
      echo $anArray[i] . "\n";
?>
```

Comment: You don't happen to be parsing comment blocks out of PHP source code with this?

Comment: I'm trying to build a php code formatter to display php code using HTML

Comment: Did you try your code before posting it here? There are basic mistakes like: i -> $i which php parser should report.

Comment: @jazzdawg: In that case use [`token_get_all`](http://php.net/token_get_all).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working code:

```
 $aString = "abcdef/*ghij*/klmn/*opqrs*/tuvwxyz";

 // SIMPLE VERSION WHERE ASTERISK MAY NOT BE IN THE COMMENT
 // \/\* is just escape sequence for /*  
 // [^\*]* - in comment may be whatever except * (asterisk)
 // \*\/ is escape sequence for */
 preg_match_all("#\/\*[^\*]*\*\/#", $aString, $anArray);

 // BETTER VERSION 
 // http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html - for explanation of ?: and ?!  
 preg_match_all("#\/\*" . "((?:(?!\*\/).)*)" . "\*\/#", $aString, $anArray);


 var_dump($anArray); // easier for debugging than for-loop
```

**Output for better version:**

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "/*ghij*/"
    [1]=>
    string(9) "/*opqrs*/"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "ghij"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "opqrs"
  }
}
```

Comment: If I put a star somewhere in there (ie: `/*gh*ij*`) it will fail

Comment: @NullUserException: Yes, I was aware of that and I've added new version which should work better.

Comment: Why are you escaping the forward slash with `\/`?

Comment: @NullUserException: I simply don't remember which characters need escaping. :-[

Answer (score 1):

To extract comment sections out of PHP code, use the [Tokenizer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.tokenizer.php).

[`token_get_all()`](http://www.php.net/token_get_all) will parse the code, and return an array of elements.

Comments will be represented as `T_COMMENT` elements.

This has the great advantage of catching all possible ways of having comments in PHP code:

```
/* This way, */

// This way

# and this way
```

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look into that

Comment: More important: It won’t give you false positives like in `$str = "/* foo */";`

Answer (score 0):

Escape the * to use it, and ad parentheses to capture the content like that : `/\*(.*)\*/`, and you should use `preg_match_all` to find all matches in your string.

(and easier than a for, use `var_dump($anArray)`)

Answer (score 0):

```
$aString = "abcdef/*ghij*/klmn/*opqrs*/tuvwxyz";
preg_match_all("/\/\*(.*?)\*\//", $aString, $anArray,PREG_SET_ORDER);
var_dump($anArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

If (as you say in one of the comments) you're attempting to display PHP code in HTML there's actually a built-in function ([highlight_file](http://www.php.net/highlight_file)) that does precisely this.

Free free to ignore if you're using this as a learning exercise, etc. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think the regex will be simple as

```
\/\*.*?\*\/
```

here's demo of a working code using regular expression tester

http://liveregex.com/WoDbk